# How to change the projection in DataGrip's Geo Viewer?

Tags: datagrip, srid

[image]

Is it possible to change the projection of the base map in DataGrip's Geo Viewer???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible at the moment I'm afraid.

Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11128